# Ruby on Rails admin password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, admin

I am trying to change the admin password for my local server.

I used following steps on terminal:

```
User.find_by(email:'admin@blah.com')
u=_
u.password='newpassword'
u.save
```

then I check to see if it was actually got changed by typing u.password,
it shows nil.

Am I missing anything here? 
Thank you.

Comment: Everyone is so busy answering that none asked what is `u=_`?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Presumably OP is running this in irb (I would guess that is what is meant by "on terminal"). The variable `_` in irb refers to the result of the last expression. It's identical to `u=User.find_by(email:'admin@blah.com')`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using `has_secure_password` in your model. It encodes your password, so it is impossible to be read through the console. This is no reason to be concerned, but rather expected security feature. Try logging in with new password and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you need to provide a `password` and a `password_confirmation` to change the actual password. Therefore try this:

```
user = User.find_by(email:'admin@blah.com')
user.password              = 'newpassword'
user.password_confirmation = 'newpassword'
user.save
```

If the does not work either, than you might want to read the error messages. Perhaps you object is not valid:

```
user.valid?
puts user.errors
# => prints list of errors
```

Read more about SecurePassword: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score -1):

You could do `u.save!` to check if the record is actually being saved or is there any exceptions (errors) thrown.